# How to fix "Unknown database type geometry requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL100Platform may not support it."

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, postgis

I am trying to prepare Symfony 3.4.32 + PostgreSQL + PostGIS environment.
I installed [jsor/doctrine-postgis](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis), but the error following happens.

> Unknown database type geometry requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL100Platform may not support it.

#### Details

I am using [EC-CUBE](https://github.com/EC-CUBE/ec-cube) 4.0.3 which is open source software using Symfony 3.4.32 .

I prepared [mdillon/postgis](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/) docker container.
I enable postgis extension and I can use PostGIS.

I installed [jsor/doctrine-postgis](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis) by composer and set up config files.

1. I added the setting to the bottom of app/config/eccube/services.yaml.

```
 services:
     # (ommitted)
      Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Event\ORMSchemaEventSubscriber:
         tags:
             - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

2. I add the three types (geography, geometry, raster) to app/config/eccube/packages/doctrine.yaml.

```
parameters:
     # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
     # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
     # environment variables are not available yet.
     # You should not need to change this value.
     env(DATABASE_URL): ''
     env(DATABASE_SERVER_VERSION): ~
 doctrine:
     dbal:
         driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
         server_version: "%env(DATABASE_SERVER_VERSION)%"
         charset: utf8

         # for mysql only
         default_table_options:
           collate: 'utf8_general_ci'

         # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
         url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'

         # types
         types:
             datetime: 'Eccube\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType'
             datetimetz: 'Eccube\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeTzType'
             geography:
                 class: 'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeographyType'
                 commented: false
             geometry:
                 class: 'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeometryType'
                 commented: false
             raster:
                 class: 'Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\RasterType'
                 commented: false
     orm:
         auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
         naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
         auto_mapping: true
         dql:
             string_functions:
                 NORMALIZE: Eccube\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Normalize
             numeric_functions:
                 EXTRACT: Eccube\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Extract
         filters:
             option_nostock_hidden:
                 class: Eccube\Doctrine\Filter\NoStockHiddenFilter
                 enabled: false
             incomplete_order_status_hidden:
                 class: Eccube\Doctrine\Filter\OrderStatusFilter
                 enabled: false
```

3. I prepared Entity, app/Customize/Entity/Geolocation.php.

```
<?php
 namespace Customize\Entity;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * GeoLocation
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="dtb_geolocation")
  * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
  * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator_type", type="string", length=255)
  * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Customize\Repository\GeoLocationRepository")
  */
 class GeoLocation extends \Eccube\Entity\AbstractEntity
 {
     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="gid", type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
      */
     public $gid;

     // (ommitted)

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="geom", type="geometry", options={"geometry_type"="MULTIPOLYGON", "srid"=4612}, nullable=true)
      */
     public $geom;
 }
```

4. Then I created the table in PostgreSQL database.

Run

```
bin/console eccube:generate:proxies
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --force
```

5. It works fine. "dtb_geolocation" table is created and checked it in PostgreSQL.

```
 db=# \d dtb_geolocation ;
                                             Table "public.dtb_geolocation "
       Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                          Default
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 gid                | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('dtb_geolocation_pkey'::regclass)

// ommitted

 geom               | geometry(MultiPolygon,4612) |           |          | NULL::geometry
 discriminator_type | character varying(255)      |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "dtb_geolocation_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
```

But when I accessed on brower, the error happens.

> Unknown database type geometry requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL100Platform may not support it.

I clear caches by `bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup`, but nothing changes.

Did I make any mistakes?
Aren't geometry type included in Symfony? How can I check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is an EC-CUBE 4 problem.
I guess the doctrine.yaml is loaded after Symfony recognizes database tables.

Comment: i'm facing same issue on my local machine . can you help me??